# Bot Joins Channel but doesn't play song

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, voice

My discord.js bot joins the channel, but doesn't play the song, I have opus,ffmpeg, and ytdl is installed. Here is my code:

```
 if (message.content.startsWith(prefix+'play')) {
      const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };
      let video = args[1]
      message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            const stream = ytdl(args[1], { filter : 'audioonly' });
            const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);
       })
        .catch(console.error);
  }
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have installed `ffmpeg` (not npm)?

Comment: I use repl.it, I assume so.

Comment: Nope, that cannot work with repl.

Comment: But replit has a console? right? command pallete